# Android Studio - how to find nearest array location of my current location

Tags: java, android, android-studio

the schema is I have 3 locations and I need to find where is the nearest location depending on my current location.

how to achieve that ?

and is it possible to use FusedLocation instead of LocationManager ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(place1.getPosition(), place2.getPosition());
        distance = (int)Math.round(distance);
```

place1 its current location

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                     
               place1 = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
```

place2 its one of our location

```
place2 = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Position 1");
```

I use this function to switch to another activity if the distance is less than 5 meters

```
if (distance <= 5) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(activity1.this, activity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: how did u create place2 ? Place2 is your list of location right ?

Comment: yes, place 2 its one of all your poits. I create it in onCreate.

Comment: thank you very much, it's work, I get it now